# Flask - how to hook into all @login_required decorated views

Tags: flask, decorator

In my Flask applicaiton I have around 30 views which are decorated with the *@login_required* decorator.
My goal is: I want to call a python method - lets call it "refreshSession()" - every time a view which is *@login_required* decorated is called.
Is there a way to hook into this decorator? I don't want to write the line "refreshSession()" 30 times.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, there's no way to hook directly into @login_required decorator.

Maybe you should try to call `refreshSession` on your Flask-Login `user_loader` function?

More information: https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.LoginManager.user_loader

Something like this:

```
from flask_login import LoginManager

login_manager = LoginManager()

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    refreshSession()
    # Fetch user from database
    user = User.get_by_id(user_id)
    return user
```

Alternatively you could create your own `login_required` decorator, and then call `refreshSession()` inside it.

`login_required` decorator source: https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/3e521a326696cafbfbebfbb80a2fbffed68e6cf3/flask_login/utils.py#L231